# Atomic transaction in django

Tags: python, django

I have a view which updates object in database. Should I make this view atomic ( `@transaction.atomic`)?
I want to eliminate data races (for example two requests update value at the same time)

My code:

```
@api_view(["POST"])
@transaction.atomic
def employee_increase(request):
    logger.info(f"Increase sallary: {request.data}")

    serializer = IdSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    employee = get_object_or_404(Employee, pk=request.data["id"])
    old_sallary = employee.sallary

    employee.sallary = int(old_sallary * (1 + int(request.data["increase_percent"]) / 100))
    employee.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a single update, you don't need to make this atomic, you can just work with an [**`.update(…)`** query <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#update):

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def employee_increase(request):
    logger.info(f"Increase sallary: {request.data}")

    serializer = IdSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    result = Employee.objects.filter(pk=request.data['id']).update(
        sallary=F('sallary') * (1 + int(request.data['increase_percent']) / 100)
    )
    if result:
        # updated (at least) one record
        pass
```

Comment: "Since this is a single update" - why does it matter? why I don't have to use  transaction.atomic?

Comment: @mascai: because such update query is inherently atomic: the query either fails (for example because the records remain locked somehow), or succeeds. We here do one query. The idea of a transaction is to obtain the data, do some other data retrieve and update queries, and these all succeed, or all fail, but here there is only one thing to succeed or fail.